# How to test callback function in function component in Jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jestjs, enzyme

If I remove callback **() =>** test completed success, but me need this callback for functionality

**Component**

```
const Slider = ({slideSelected, slides}) => {
  const slideClicked = slide => () => { // can't test this
    slideSelected(slide);
  };

  const renderSlide = item => (
    <Slide
      slideClicked={slideClicked}
      item={item}
    />
  );

  return (
    <Carousel
      data={slides}
      renderItem={renderSlide}
    />
  );
};
```

**test**

```
const slideSelectedFunc = jest.fn();
wrapper.setProps({
  slides: [{ title: 'hello' }],
  slideSelected: slideSelectedFunc,
})
const Item = sliderShallowWrapper.find('Carousel').prop('renderItem');
const itemShallowWrapper = shallow(<Item item={[{ title: 'hello' }]} />);
itemShallowWrapper.props().slideClicked();
expect(slideSelectedFunc).toHaveBeenCalled(); // error
```

Version Jest 24.9

Comment: Simulate the click event that triggers it? Even in class components where that might be exposed as a method, calling it directly is testing the implementation, not the behaviour.

Comment: I think with function component it is impossible to test. But class component might work for you. Even though, testing implementation details is not a very good idea. Take a look at the [react testing library](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/intro) it follows some of  the testing best practices.

Comment: I think you have to separate the components by refactoring and test it independently. That makes you complicated.

Comment: Is enzyme or @testing-library/react?

Comment: Is enzyme (but now it is deprecated)